# Unable to click on a "text" link in google search page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to click on News link on google search page the HTML structure looks like this
[image]

I tried following xpaths but none worked

```
//a/child::span[1][contains(.,'News')]
```

The following xpath resulted in invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a/child::span/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'News')]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

```
//a/child::span/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'News')]
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You simply need

```
//a[contains(., "News")]
```

Note that `"News"` is not a part of `span`, but `a`, so your 1st XPath won't work

Answer (score 1):

`//a[contains(.,'News')]` might return this link, but may result in a list of more than one element that you'd need to handle and select the right element from.

You can use Selenium's SearchContext to specify a container element, or solve it using an xpath one-liner like: `//div[@role='navigation']//a[contains(.,'News')]` (Effectively searching for a link that contains 'News' somewhere in it's html-tree, somewhere inside a div that has a role attribute with value 'navigation').